# Magento 2 mode online store

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Which Mode usually should be use for Magento 2 online store?

**Default Mode** or **Production Mode** ?

Comment: You can get more info from here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Answer (score 0):

For the live store, one should always use Production mode.

**Reasons:**
Intended for deployment on a production system, this mode:

- Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs
  only).
- Serves static view files from cache only.
- Prevents automatic code file compilation. New or updated files are
  not written to the file system.
- Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Magento Admin.

This improves performance because static files don’t go through the fallback mechanism; instead, URLs for static files are created as needed.

Comment: Why my store is slow with production mode? Default mode all web pages loading faster.

Comment: You may need to sever level optimizations required to make your website load faster in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is live then you should run it on "Production mode".

Answer (score -1):

Live Store should be in **`Production Mode`**.

TO enable Production Mode :

**`bin/magento maintenance:enable`**

**`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`**

**`bin/magento s:d:c`** // For compilation

**`bin/magento s:up`** // Upgrade Data

**`bin/magento s:s:d`** // If your M2 version is 2.2.x than add -f , Will generate static files

**`bin/magento cache:enable`**

**`bin/magento maintenance:disable`**

Read about Shotcuts at [Here](https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/wiki/Magento-CLI-shortcuts)

Comment: What mean these two commands? bin/magento s:d:c and bin/magento s:up

Comment: Check my Update.

Comment: hey Why Downvote ??? :(

Comment: Why my store is slow with production mode? Default mode all web pages loading faster.

Comment: Try to execute `setup:static-content:deploy` to generate static files and also apply 777 permissions to var and pub folder.